# Webpage sometimes work other times don't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, vuejs2

Good night,

It's not easy to explain (my english not the best too) what's happend but i will try my best.

The problem is, i have a big "contact form" with some inputs like name, age, and email adress and 95 switch inputs. The objective is to do some calculations and return an email with 2 tables. 1 table with the switch's seleted's and other table with calculations, sometimes the code work well and do all the stuff but other times code don't work, don't send the email and dont do nothing.
I can check in server side (cpanel) the email track delivery and is all ok the server was accepted the email.

I can't understand what is happening, and i'm thankful if you can help me.

I will put all code here so you guys can check and help me found what i'm doing wrong.

i will put here the php if you need some other stuff i will post later

```
...


$array = $_POST['role'];
//print_r ($array);

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'mail.jobzone.pt';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'questionario@jobzone.pt';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxx';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('questionario@jobzone.pt');
$mail->addAddress($_POST['EA_mail']);     // Add a recipient 

$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Questionario Vitamina-te do(a) ' . $_POST['name'];
$mail->Body    = '



<table style="text-align: center; border-spacing: 5px; border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;">
  <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;"> Sintomas Selecionados </th>';
                    foreach($array as $item) { 
                         $mail->Body .= '<tr>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">' . $item . '</td>
                        </tr>';
                     } 
$mail->Body .= '</table>



<br><br><br> 





<table style="text-align: center; border-spacing: 5px; border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">Nutriente</th>
                            <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">Sintomas Calculados</th> 
                            <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">Max Sintomas</th>
                            <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">Racio % Calculado</th>
                            <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">Necessidade</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">Vitamina A</td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">' . $_POST['vitamA'] . '</td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">9</td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">'.$ratio_vitA.'</td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px; background-color:'. $color_vitA . ';">'.$necessidade_vitA.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">Vitamina B1</td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">' . $_POST['vitamB1'] . '</td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">18</td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;">'.$ratio_vitB1.'</td>
                            <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px; background-color:'. $color_vitB1 . ';">'.$necessidade_vitB1.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>



...

</table>';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  header("Location: https://jobzone.pt/thanks.html");
}
?>
```

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no... depends on any filled values/fields in form? Are you checked spam in the recipient mailbox?

Comment: yeh i check spam and is nothing there. yeh i think when i put more than 8 or 9 idk the correct values switch on it dont pass the email

Comment: How looks `$mail->Body` of any failed message (for example I see unsanitized variables, when in any field is `'` it can cause any problems)? Please upload somewhere whole 'incorrect' html. What smtpDebug says?

Comment: This PHP code looks good, so you need to simulate situation when mail doesn't arrive to recipient and then work with that. With the same filled form, with generated HTML in mail body, ...

Comment: Ok i will test more this, i have problems with server supplier because It Block my acc if i try the email send too much times (support guy said is to prevent spam blocks). But i will try more tomorrow and put here some news. Thanks

Comment: 10, 20, 30 emails per hour can't be problem with correctly setting of mail server. Now I can't help you more... And change your pass to email account, I've changed it here, but edits are public here (never paste your credentials to internet).

Comment: No problem with password is generated and i will change now. I will test and try to see where is the problem. Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying with all my knowladge but i can't figure out what's happend with this. I can put here the SMTPDebug if you think that can help. But idk what's happend the email e out from the server but i dont receive it on email recipent. gratz

Comment: you should read into how you can simply write some variables to a log file and then wait for the error and read it. You also use those post variables unfiltered, that can result in unexpectated behaviour.